# How to access the last added element in a dynamic rows component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows

This is a follow up question to [How to add custom Js code in a "dynamic-rows" component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/139077/146)

I have successfully overwritten the [dynamic rows](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows.js) ui-component so I can call some custom js code when a new element is added.
but I cannot access the element that was last added.
I've changed the function `addChild` to look like this:

```
   addChild: function (data, index, prop) {
        this._super(data, index, prop);
        console.log('just added an element');
        console.log(this.recordData().length); //tried with this.elems().lenght also
        return this;
    },
```

This works partially as expected. The message `'just added an element'` is logged in the console each time I add a new element, but when logging the number of added elements it turns up one short.
After the first add I get the length `0` after the second one I get `1` and so on.
How can I access the last element that I added to the list of dynamic rows.

**[EDIT]**
The same thing happens when I try to log the number of elements after a delete. I get one more than I should.
So I guess there is a method that updates the child elements count after the elements are added or deleted. Which is it?

Comment: Why not use the `index` or the `prop` given to the method ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. Tried that. index is null and it is calculated based on the number of elements that already exist. So when I have 1 element, the next index is `1`, but it returns `null` when I try to get the element with id 1. That's why I'm saying that something is adding the elements to the child elements after the item is added to the dom.